# Cloud Foundry not recognizing @Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have two applications.  We will call them MyApp1 and MyApp2.  MyApp1 works both locally and deployed to PCF with the @Transactional Tag.  I am able to query and read from DB's using spring JDBC.  MyApp2 works locally and works fine without any errors.  However when I push MyApp2 to cloud foundry I begin getting the strangest error:

```
"Failed to obtain JDBC Connection: Cannot execute JDBC statements outside of a Transaction. Define @Transactional(readOnly="true") or @Transactional for all methods"
```

One other thing to note is that both applications use the same MyDAOJar which has the @Transactional within it, so MyApp1 and MyApp2 are literally using the exact same code.  To get spring to recognize the annotations within MyDAOJar I have the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
"org.MyApp1",
"org.MyDaoJar"})

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
"org.MyApp2",
"org.MyDaoJar"})
```

One last thing to note is that if I put @Transactional within MyApp2, just above the call to MyDAOJar, it begins working in PCF, so its like for some strange reason, spring is unable to see that @Transactionl in MyDAOJar with MyApp2.  I have checked my config between MyApp1 and MyApp2 like 10 times and do not see any differences.

Comment: Try starting your app on CF with `--debug`. Spring Boot will use this to turn on additional debugging, including showing how automatic configuration is being done. It's possible something is dynamically being enabled locally but not in CF. Hard to say for sure with the given info. Oh, also check if you're using profiles. The Java buildpack will automatically turn on the "cloud" profile, which can change how your app is started.

Comment: Hello,  I have the exact same stuff in my cloud profile in both the working and non working application.  I will try running with --debug to see if anything useful pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely,  All I ended up needing to do was move any Bean that was returned a map, into its on @Configuration class of its own (aka out of my main configuration class), and the error went away.  Why I have no idea, so if someone could help me understand, that would be great!

Thanks,
Brian